# Best way to the last byte from a file with fstream?

Tags: c++, fstream

I am generating a CSV file, and of course I get the wonderful trailing comma at the end

```
data1, data2, data3,
data1, data2, data3,
data1, data2, data3,
data1, data2, data3,
```

Can I use the fstream facilities to remove the last comma?  I am more familiar with the C fopen and so I'm a bit out of water, and just looking for a quick, best-practices solution.

Comment: If you want to read bytes, you need `filebuf`, not `fstream`.

Comment: if you are generating that data , why not generate without the last `,` ?

Comment: I don't know about best practices but if you lookup istream::seekg http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/  it is similar to fseek.  istream::tellg is similar to ftell.  Use these in the same way that you would use fseek/fwrite to remove the last comma.

Comment: @rightfold `std::fstream` can be used to read bytes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this with streams is to write your output to a temp buffer / file (e.g. `std::stringstream`), and then copy all but the last comma to the final destination.

A better approach would be to make sure the last comma never appears in the first place.