# How to erase last comma when writing to a file

Tags: c++

I'm using the following snippet to write values to a .txt file:

```
fstream f1;
f1.open("output.txt", ios::out);
{
    for (const auto& avg : clusAvg)
    {
        f1 << avg << ",";
    }
}
f1.close();
```

This generates a list that looks like: 20,30,40,50,

My question is, how can I eliminate that last comma in the list?

Comment: Write the comma first before the number, not after.  Then figure out if the number you're writing is the first one in the list.

Comment: Well, you eliminate that by knowing (i.e., tracking) that you haven't written any values yet.

Comment: Related/dupes: [Remove trailing comma in CSV file written for a vector using copy and ostream_iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33094317/1782792), [Best way to the last byte from a file with fstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22831846/1782792).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this

```cpp
fstream f1;
f1.open("output.txt", ios::out);
{
    bool first = true;
    for (const auto& avg : clusAvg)
    {
        if(!first) f1 << ", ";
        first = false;

        f1 << avg;
    }
}
f1.close();
```

Comment: Thank you, was the first answered. Worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You can write out a comma for all but the last element, and then write the last element:

```
if (! clusAvg.empty())
{
  for (auto i = 0u; i < clusAvg.size() - 1; ++i)
    f1 << clusAvg[i] << ", ";
  f1 << clusAvg.back();
}
```